# Save PWD but not OTP with networkmanager openconnect

Tags: network-manager, openconnect

I have a few VPN connections of the openconnect / Cisco AnyConnet type.

[image: login dialog]

If I select Save passwords here, and there is also a second stage with a one time password provided by SMS, this OTP will also be saved an the connection will fail the next time.
Is there a way around this? I don't even know where to start looking...

This is 18.04.5 LTS btw.

Comment: For me it doesnt even show me the otp box to enter the otp.